# iOS - Can you embed WiFi Network credentials in a button

Tags: ios

To support a live event we were playing with the idea of allowing the WiFi credentials to be easily accessed in the supporting app - such as clicking a button - to open the credentials/store them on the device so they can work (similar to using a profile without the agg of installing).

Is this something that can be done? Trying to not use QR codes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using `NEHotspotConfiguration` and `NEHotspotConfigurationManager`

```
let config = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: "ssid", passphrase: "secret", isWep: false)
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(config) { ... }
```